# Plot quantiles in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, subset, quantile

I'm trying to find the mean, mean ± standard deviation and certain quantiles (5%, 50%, 95%) for the columns of a matrix.

The matrix has dimensions 10*20 (row indicate sample number, column indicates time):

[image]

Now, from this dataset, I would like to find the quantiles as above. I tried the following:

[image]

But the functions give me only a single value. I am hoping to get the above meansures (means, standard deviations, quantiles) for *each* time.

Then, how do we plot a graph where the **x axis** is the time *t* (*t*=1 to *t*=20), the **y axis** is the Fund value and all 5 lines are shown (mean, mean ± standard deviation, 5% quantile, 50% quantile and 95% quantile).

Your kind help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

`apply` will let you apply a function to each row or column of a matrix. You define the matrix, the dimension to apply to (rows=1, columns=2), the function (e.g. `quantile`), and additional arguments for the function.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
Fund <- matrix(rnorm(20*10), ncol=20, nrow=10)
qs <- apply(Fund, 2, quantile, probs=c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95))
qs
ylim=range(qs)
plot(seq(ncol(Fund)), qs[1,], t="l", lty=2, ylim=ylim) #5%
lines(seq(ncol(Fund)), qs[2,], lty=1, lwd=2) #50%
lines(seq(ncol(Fund)), qs[3,], lty=2, col=2)  #95%
legend("topleft", legend=rev(rownames(qs)), lwd=c(1,2,1), col=c(2,1,1), lty=c(2,1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: And how do we print the label next to the plot?

I have tried

text(locator(), labels = c("5% quantile", "50% quantile","95% quantile"))

but nothing happen

Comment: @Nor Abd - I'm confused by your ask here, so I can't provide too much help.  But, have you tried exploring the ggplot2 & reshape pacakges?

Comment: @NorAbd - I have now added a legend to the plot. It's unclear to me what else you were hoping to do here.

Comment: From my understanding, in order to find a quantile, we first sort the values in ascending. For example, i have 10 sample of data at time t=1 which is [2,3,4,5,8,9,11,12,19,20].To get 25% of quantile, we then calculate it as 25% x 10samples = 2.5. So it means that the quantiles is in between the second and third samples. So, the 25% quantiles should be (3+4)/2 = 3.5. right? However, if you look at my sample, for eg at t=1, the sample values are all 66.7. How can the quantiles be way different from the sample? (95% quantiles = 1.645).Can someone explain to me? or do i have a wrong concept here?

Comment: @NorAbd - This is not a statistics forum. I suggest you look elsewhere if you are looking for the underlying mathematics behind the function. Start with `?quantile`